# Can someone explain why this matrix is unitary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, complex-numbers, unitarity

I have a matrix 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    e^{i\theta}b^* & -e^{i\theta}a^*
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where $\theta$ is a real number, and $a$ and $b$ are complex number such that $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$.

So, I believe what I am trying to prove is that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & e^{-i\theta}b \\
    b & -e^{-i\theta}a
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    e^{i\theta}b^* & -e^{i\theta}a^*
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

since a unitary matrix means that $U^{\dagger}U = I$.

I am getting 
$$
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    a^2 + bb^* & ab - ba^* \\
    ab - ab^* & b^2 + aa^*
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    a^2 + bb^* & b(a - a^*) \\
    a(b - b^*) & b^2 + aa^*
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This doesn't make sense because $a-a^*$ and $b-b^*$ would have to equal $0$, which means $a$ and $b$ would have to be real, which doesn't satisfy the original condition. I'm also not sure how I would get $a^2 + bb^*$ and $b^2 + aa^*$ equal to $1$.

Comment: Because a and b have to allow any complex number.

Comment: If you do the math correctly it works. Go double check your math and the definition of a unitary matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to take complex conjugate everywhere, where it is needed. Correctly:
$$U^\dagger U = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a^* & e^{-i\theta}b \\
    b^* & -e^{-i\theta}a
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    e^{i\theta}b^* & -e^{i\theta}a^*
\end{bmatrix} = I
$$